# Can empty lines be displayed as something else in Vim?

Tags: vim

I want my Vim to display empty lines as a string of `###` characters, like so:

[image: Desired display of empty lines]

I would like it to be work similarly to how I replace my tabs char to `>---` with `set listchars=tab:>-`. Just display it that way, not actually insert them.

Also, it would be great if it could adapt to size of my terminal.

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible.

Comment: That screenshot looks like a "show whitespace" editor mode - but I don't know what editor it is.

Comment: @FrankBro might seem that way, but I don't believe there's a way to display characters for something that doesn't exist. There is :help conceal and :help listchars, but these don't cover this particular example.

Comment: @FrankBro - Why would you like that? Is there some reason behind it?

Comment: @ldigas It helps me see better. Same reason why I use ">---" for tabs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The desired effect can be achieved via folding. If we create one-line
folds separately containing empty lines of a buffer, they all will be
marked out as folded. The only thing left will be to customize the
highlighting accordingly.

First of all, we need to automatically create the folds. For this
purpose, we can switch folding to the `expr` method and then set
the `foldexpr` option to evaluate to a non-zero value for empty
lines only:

```
:setl foldmethod=expr
:setl foldexpr=empty(getline(v:lnum))
```

What we should do next for the trick to work out is to make those
folds close automatically in order to trigger the folding
highlighting:

```
:setl foldminlines=0
:setl foldlevel=0
:set foldclose=all
```

Finally, to repeat a custom character in the folding line, we just
empty the text displayed for a closed fold, and change the filling
character:

```
:setl foldtext=''
:set fillchars+=fold:#
```

Combining the above commands in one function for convenience,
we obtain the following:

```
function! FoldEmptyLine()
    setl foldmethod=expr
    setl foldexpr=empty(getline(v:lnum))
    setl foldminlines=0
    setl foldlevel=0
    set foldclose=all
    setl foldtext=''
    set fillchars+=fold:#
endfunction
```

The downside of this trick, of course, is that it interferes with the
usual applications of folding, and cannot be easily used without
modifications if the user extensively relies on folding for other
purposes.

Comment: See also [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6997274/254635) to similar question "[Page feed symbol display in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5347522/254635)".